# Triggering Google Analytics on a direct image/pdf view on a web server?

Tags: javascript, php, image, pdf, google-analytics

So basically I'm trying to trigger a page view in google analytics when someone directly visits an image or pdf, rather than when the image is on a page. E.g https://example.com/i/image.jpg. Is there anyway I can do this? Thank you for reading, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE BASED ON SERVER-SIDE REQUIREMENTS

If you want to track direct hits to assets that cannot run javascript (e.g. images and documents), there is no simple way to do this, and is not possible with the GA javascript library. When I say direct hits, I mean where the user has accessed assets outside of your normal web workflow e.g. a link from an email, document, direct download etc.

It CAN be done, but can require a lot of setup that I can't answer here (mostly due to having no knowledge about your tech stack), but I will go high level so you can lookup more specific answers that might give you a steer if you need it.

The simpler approach is not use GA for this at all and just use server logs to find what assets are being served and from where they are being requested.

If you need the traffic to show in GA from a server-side request, you will need to the Google Analytics ["Measurement protocol"](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1) which is just the api used by GA to send data to their servers. You will also need to put a process in place between the request and the asset, and this isn't straightforward especially if you are trying to add tracking to existing assets that are being used on web.

The problem is that the handler needs to be intercepted so you are doing something like this:-

1. User requests your image "https://example.com/i/image.jpg"
2. You have an Http handler that detects all requests to image assets (for example). How this is done is entirely dependent on your framework (e.g. php, C#, nodejs) and is fairly common practice, but not always straightforward and may require fiddling with your web server (maybe, this can also be handled directly in the web project) so the webserver knows to go via your code rather than just serving it up directly.
3. In the code for the handler you call the GA Measurement protocol, filling in the details that you want to see in your GA traffic reports
4. Complete the request by sending the image in the response

Another way of looking at it is to think of it as an api request that does a portion of work before delivering the image as a response. This method of image tracking is how 3rd party cookies work, and how tracking email "opens" work.

I'm sorry that this a how-to guide for your issue, but the question is so broad it's difficult to answer precisely.

=================

Using a variety of methods, you can trigger an event when someone clicks on the element. How you do this depends on what framework you are using, how you have implemented the markup and whether you are using GTM or straight GA on the page, which also depends on the GA version (async, universal, gtag).

The simplest method, using Universal Analytics, would look something like this

```
<a href="/image.jpg" target="_blank"

    onclick="ga('send', 'event','Click','Image','Image opened: ' + this.href)"

>View the image</a>
```

Few things to note

- use a target so the image or pdf will open in a new window. This will also allow the event to fire without accidentally getting stopped by the browser, and you don't need to return false or anything like that
- 'Click' is the category, 'Image' is the action and last bit is the label - these are arbitrary bits of text and can be whatever you want
- this.href is pulling the current image src dynamically to use in the name
- this method is super inefficient because you potentially need to manually tag a lot of items
- this method would make a lot of devs cry because of the inline code

The question needs a bit of refinement, because there are lot of different ways this can be accomplished depending on the setup. What you want is a generic bit of code that is a catchall, here is something that uses jQuery, that uses event delegation.

```
$(document).on("click","a[href*='.pdf'],a[href*='.jpg']",function() {
   ga('send', 'event','Click','Document','Opened: ' + this.href);
});
```

This would also make devs cry, because the current trend is to stay away from jQuery (and it's a bit efficient).

But hopefully you can get the gist

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! So the problem I've been facing is more when someone directly visits the image, say they get sent a direct link to the image in a chat or an email by another person (who isn't me) where I can't load a HTML page first.

Comment: Have amended my answer. It's basically "no with a but"